# Does freezing apps in Titanium Backup Pro require a phone reboot to take effect?

Tags: reboot, titanium-backup, disable-app

When freezing apps using Titanium Backup Pro, do I have to reboot for the freeze to take effect? (e.g. not be started anymore, even if applicaple Intent is fired off?)

Does it depend on whether the app is a system one or not?

If it matters, environment is Droid X (Stock 2.2 Froyo, rooted), latest Market version of TBPro.

I tried checking on TB Wiki and found zero reference to rebooting or not as far as freezing functionality.

---

Here's a specific example: consider the following sequence:

1. "GPS location changed" intent fires off.
2. A mapping application "MyGMaps" which is registered for this intent is started to handle it
3. I kill that application's process(es) - all of them - via Advanced Task Killer
4. I freeze "MyGMaps" via Titanium Backup Pro
5. At this point, "MyGMaps" process is NOT running
6. "GPS location changed" intent fires off again
7. What happens here? Will "MyGMaps" be started again due to the intent in #6, despite the fact that it's "Frozen"?

My understanding is that, once I reboot the phone after freezing, the app will no longer start at all. **But what happens in step #7, right after the freeze but without a reboot?**

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to restart after freezing an app. Once you freeze the app, it should disappear from the apps drawer.

Comment: I'm less interested in whether it's in an apps drawer than whether it will be started (e.g. if the frozen app is registered for an intent that fires off when GPS location changes, will it STILL fire off on GPS location change until you reboot?

Comment: If the app you freeze is sending the intent, then no the intent will no longer happen. But if the app is receiving intents, then yes it should still receive them.

Comment: @hillie - meaning it will launch and run?

Comment: meaning it will preform a task given to it by another app. that's it. It will not launch and run on its own.

Comment: Please see specific example in the question

Comment: See my last comment.

Comment: Please roll up your clarifications into the answer so I can upvote and accapt

Comment: a frozen app only works when an intent is sent to it. otherwise it doesn't start or work. Even when an intent is sent to it, after its done it freeze again (and it only does the specified task). It can not send intents or do anything else. If you want to stop apps from sending intents to it, you will most likely have to uninstall it. Does that fully answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Though "Even when an intent is sent to it, after its done it freeze again (and it only does the specified task)" seems contrary to what people were selling the whole "Freeze" idea on! :(

Comment: Actually, not what I read. Why else would it be a better idea to freeze and app instead of uninstall it?

Comment: @Chillie would you please integrate your comments with your answer? They are far to useful to be kept "down here"! If you could also include a reference to a frozen app acting on intents (I fully believe this, it explains a lot! I still wish to understand the "why"), that would be great! I already upvoted in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Freezing an app is similar to uninstalling it, in that it won't be able to run (whether by the user wanting to load it or via any intents). However, since it is frozen and not actually uninstalled, it does still take up space.

If you freeze a system app, you may have to reboot your phone. This usually isn't needed, but sometimes your home screen app may have a problem with a system app missing. Whether or not you reboot, though, the system app is frozen and will not be able to run.

A user app, however, can be frozen without needing a reboot.

Comment: If that were so, I wonder why some apps, while frozen, still show active processes -- even after a reboot. I guess the explanation is given by Chillie's comments on his answer, that a frozen app still is able to receive broadcasts.