# Disable service permanently

Tags: task-management, services

I would like to disable some services/apps on the Android. Some run that I do not want to.  I do not want to have to stop the service every time I turn off the phone for obvious reasons.

Comment: Is that any system service? Please give more details

Comment: I used TB to freeze the apps. Not optimal but I didn't have that many to do.

Answer (score 3):

As I've read in different places: Freezing apps does not necessarily mean their services won't be running anymore. It seems even frozen apps are able to react on broadcasts, so freezing alone won't solve the issue. Reference:

- *If the app you freeze is sending the intent, then no the intent will no longer happen. But if the app is receiving intents, then yes it should still receive them.* ([ASE](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19204/16575))

The solution would be to use an app like e.g. [Autorun Manager PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun.pro) (yes, the pro -- the free version is limited here) to disable separate listeners, so the corresponding services will no longer be started. A free alternative might be [AutoStart Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.autostart.manager) which I have not tested myself:

[image: AutoRun Manager] [image: AutoStart Manager]
<sup>AutoRun Manager / AutoStart Manager (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Having disabled the corresponding listener, the app (frozen or not) should no longer receive the broadcast for the event it usually reacts on, so it will no longer start on that event, and thus no longer be running -- unless started manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) (or similar software) to freeze or uninstall the services/apps you don't want to use.

Be careful since you might break the system if some needed apps/services are not found.